# Notifications delivered to both device and app when app is running in the foreground on iOS using Cordova Firebase Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an interesting issue I am trying to resolve on iOS using the plugin cordova-plugin-firebase (https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase).  Sending notification works fine through Firebase Console or cURL code, however notifications are always delivered to both the device notification center and displayed in the app even when it is the foreground. According to the documentation the notification flow should be that the notification is not delivered to the device when app when in the foreground. I have not made any modifications in app delegate or plugin code etc.. so I'm not exactly sure where to begin debugging this.

Here is the onNotificationOpen callback in my code, it does get called whenever the app is the foreground or whenever a notification is opened a expected just really confused by the notification being delivered to the device as well.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
console.log(notification);
alert(notification);
 }, function(error) {
   console.error(error);
});
```

Cordova iOS platform is 4.5.5. cordova-plugin-firebase is 2.0.3, device iOS is 12.0

Comment: Oops, I jumped the gun posting this, turns out it's a bug in the plugin https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/817

Comment: Simple solution for me was to add UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone instead of UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert in the complete handler in AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m as discussed here: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/pull/835

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for notifications.

The dashboards are user friendly and you can segment your devices and send notifications to specific devices.

Here is the link to the [setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup)